# "Lying supine" vs. "supine"

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, word-usage, adjectives, redundancy

Is it natural to say "lying supine"?

The word ***supine***, by definition, already suggests *lying* [See: http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/supine]. However, I was just confused because one of the sample sentences from the Learner's Dictionary goes this way:
***He was lying supine on the couch.***

I hope someone can shed some light on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'Lying supine' is just another example of the type of redundant description that is so common in English, like 'hollow tube', 'period of time', 'free gift', 'frozen ice' etc.

If you're interested in reading more examples, you'll find an extensive list of them [here](http://grammar.about.com/od/words/a/redundancies.htm).

Comment: Thank you for sharing this information. :) Indeed, it sounds awkward to use "lying" with "supine." I wonder why Learner's Dictionary included a sample sentence with that phrase.

Comment: @phantomthief - Good point. I think we often grow up hearing expressions like this, and because they are such familiar collocations, we tend not to inspect them more closely or question their usefulness. I suspect that sometimes the redundant element is used to add rhetorical impact even though it adds no descriptive value. Probably the compilers of the Learner's Dictionary, on the other hand, were just being complacent or lazy.

Comment: Just to be sure, I also sent them this concern. I also want to hear their take on this. ^_^

Answer (score 2):

As a medical term, *supine* denotes a position or orientation, eg. "with the patient supine". The opposite is *prone* (stomach to floor).

Technically, it's not really redundant to say *lying supine* (ie. What are you doing? Lying. In what orientation? Supine'), although it's hard to be supine if you're not actually laying down!

Comment: I actually think the terms prone and supine imply laying down. You don't use either term standing up. I use them everyday while conferring with several colleagues in relation to biomechanics and we never use them unless considering laying down positions.

Comment: @StanShunpike: no, the terms aren't limited to laying down (medically anyway) eg. the forearm can be in a prone position, although for non-forearms, you would generally say ventral or dorsal. Prone for the forearm is quite common though.

Comment: Huh. Although we only use it in laying positions, I have heard it used that way in relation to forearms.

Comment: It is a bit odd isn't it? While 'forearm in prone position' is used a bit, I must admit I've never heard someone describe a forearm as 'supine'. It's advisable to stick to the strictly defined anatomical terms (ventral/dorsal). 'Rostral' is another one: cute, rarely used, but defined as 'beak' or 'nose' forward!

Comment: @StanShunpike - You are using prone and supine correctly. When anatomists (or doctors) describe a forearm with the palm upward relative to the ground, the forearm is *pronated*, not prone; *supinated* means palm facing the ground.

Comment: @medica thank you for clarifying. That makes much more sense. That agrees with how we use it with respect to the foot, ankle, tibia as well. Runners talk about this issue all the time with excessive *pron*ation and *supin*ation.

Comment: @Pete855217 - see above comment. Medically (and [anatomically](http://www.medicinenet.com/script/main/art.asp?articlekey=9210)), supine is defined as "With the back or dorsal surface downward (*lying face up*), as opposed to prone." Note also that we can pronate or supinate only our forearms/palms and lower legs/feet.

Comment: @Pete855217 - e.g. "James Tao, MD, PhD, associate professor, neurology, and director, electroencephalography (EEG) laboratory, University of Chicago, Illinois, and colleagues carried out a systematic review and meta-analysis that showed patients with epilepsy, especially those under age 40, are at increased risk for SUDEP when in a prone position." As you probably know, people with grand-mal seizures "GTG" (go to ground).

Comment: @medica: yes that is more accurate. Informally, 'move to prone position' sounds like something the therapist does to the patient, compared to 'pain on pronation' or 'pronate the arm' sounds like something the patient does (or attempts).

Comment: @StanShunpike: yes you hear 'pronated' and 'supinated' a lot with feet and runners: I'm not sure how this is derived, but am assuming it's reflective of the anatomical position that's exaggerated eg. 'over'-pronated.